# getJSONArray() in GraphResponse Cannot be applied to java.lang.String - Facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

i have develop a android application integrate with facebook login now i want to make facebook app invite function(invitable_friends api) but in my code i got red underline errors.

```
  private void loadFriendsFromFacebook(final String str) {
    final AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), str, null, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                List<String> s = new ArrayList();
                List<String> F = new ArrayList();
                List<String> G = new ArrayList();
                String t = "";
                String u = "";
                int w = 0;
                boolean x = false;
                String[] y = new String[2];
                String E = "";
                OnInviteListener onInviteListener = null;

                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = getSharedPreferences("friendsData", 0).edit();

                    try {
                int i;
                JSONArray jSONArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (i = 0; i < jSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    this.s.add(jSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(Page.Properties.ID));
                }
                for (i = 0; i < jSONArray.length(); i++) {
                    this.G.add(jSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(Page.Properties.PICTURE).getJSONObject("data").getString("url"));
                    edit.putString("friendPhoto", jSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(Page.Properties.PICTURE).getJSONObject("data").getString("url"));
                    this.F.add(jSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(Page.Properties.NAME));
                    edit.putString("friendName", jSONArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(Page.Properties.NAME));
                }
                edit.commit();
                for (i = 0; i < this.s.size(); i++) {
                    this.u += ((String) this.s.get(i)) + ",";
                }
                JSONObject jSONObject2 = response.getJSONObject("paging");
                if (jSONObject2.toString().contains("next")) {
                    this.t = jSONObject2.getString("next").toString();
                } else if (this.s.size() < 1) {
                    this.x = true;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception=" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).executeAsync();

}
```

where the response.getJSONArray("data");

data is underline red which is click rover shows getJSONArray() in graphrespone cannot be applied to java.lang.sting..

and same error in the response.getJSONObject("paging");

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in the code?
it will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphResponse/) I can see that `getJSONObject()` and `getJSONArray()` do not have parameters at all. You should retrieve the object respective the array from the `GraphResponse` using this methods and once you have a `JsonObject` or `JsonArray` you can access specific fields.

`response.getJSONArray()` will give you an object of type `JSONArray` and `response.getJSONObject()` will give you an object of type `JSONObject`. Using this objects you can access the fields using `jsonObject.getString("user_id")` or similar (see docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

Comment: "You should retrieve the object respective the array from the GraphResponse using this methods" Can you plz tell me more abt this ?

Comment: added more detailed explanation

Comment: hy, sry im newbie in developing.. can you plz tell me exact code ? so i can put it in my class